# vimのlangmapでキー配列を変更したときのマクロ動作について

Tags: vim

eucalyn配列のキーボードを使用してvimのlangmapで以下のような設定しています。

```
set langmap=\\,e,\\.r,\\;t,by,ru,di,yo,pp,os,ed,if,fg,gh,tj,sl,h\\;,ub,j\\,,l\\.,<E,>R,+T,BY,RU,DI,YO,OS,ED,IF,FG,GH,TJ,SL,H+,UB,J<,L>
```

この設定でvimのマクロを登録及び実行するとき、
実行時は設定したlangmapが無効化されているみたいですが
これを無効化されなくする方法はあるのでしょうか。

具体例としては以下のような動作になってしまいます。

1. マクロ登録でqqttqで2行下移動するマクロを登録
2. @qでマクロを実行してもlangmapで割り当てる前のttが実行されtの手前に移動してしまう